# How to use ajax to call a boolean web method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to use an ajax call to check if Boolean is true or false.
here is my web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public Boolean Login(string uname, string password)
{
    if (ValidateUser(uname, password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(uname, password);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and here is my ajax call but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        var username = "test"
        var password = "1234"
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "wsLogin.asmx/Login",
            data: "{uname: '" + username + "'" + ",pwd: '" + password + "' }",
            dataType: "Json",
            success: function (success) {

                alert("Boolean True");
            },
            error: function (error) {

                alert("Boolean False");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to create a login so I am using a Boolean to check if the user is authenticated

Comment: What do you mean by not working? specific error or something?

Comment: the error function doesn't mean that your service call returned false, the returned value is in the success parameter

Comment: yes its not working. I need the alert to say true or false

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ajax seems to .toString() the answer so what was a boolean becomes a "True" or "False" if you return a Json data structure instead like

```
 return Json(new { Error = true, ErrorMessages = new []{e.Message} });
```

the values will be truly boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I realised that the `error: function (error) {}` never gets called, even when my `webmethod` returned `false`.

What's actually happening is that as long as the webmethod does not produce any errors itself (like exceptions), then the error function will never fire! The webmethod will always be a 'success'!

So place your true/false logic inside the success function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            var username = "test"
            var password = "1234"
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "wsLogin.asmx/Login",
                data: "{uname: '" + username + "'" + ",pwd: '" + password + "' }",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if(result == "true")
                        alert("Boolean True");
                    else
                        alert("Boolean False");
                },
                error: function (error) {

                    error = error; //do nothing
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            var username = "test"
            var password = "1234"
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "wsLogin.asmx/Login",
                data: "{uname: '" + username + "'" + ",pwd: '" + password + "' }",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data)
                        alert("Boolean True");
                    else
                        alert("Boolean False");
                },
                error: function (error) {

                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: it returns Boolean true when the condition is false